# Outlook 2013 Addin Get All Shared calendars

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a outlook addin that will look what all shared calendars are added in outlook and then try to resolve all those calendar names from Exchange.

The problem I am facing, how to access all shared calendar added to outlook.
I can access shared calendar using

```
Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder("recipient",Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
```

But I don't have recipient. All I want to do is access all the shared calendars that are already added in my outlook.

Is there a way to do this ?